# Do all members of the affine Toda field theories have fermion duals?

Tags: fermions, duality, integrable-systems

I know that the sine-Gordon model is $S$-dual to the massive Thirring model. Since sine-Gordon is a special case of affine Toda theory I was wondering if this extends to the generality of the models?

Comment: This seems relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9905221